# Can I install Outlook 2007 when I already have Office 2010 Home?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I purchased a new computer using Windows 7 and to my dismay it did not come with MS Outlook.  Since I have already purchased the Office 2007 for my laptop, can I install just the Outlook 2007 to use with the already purchased and installed Office 2010? I do not want to purchase the MS Outlook 2010 when I have MS Outlook 2007 along with the entire package of Microsoft Office Professional 2007.  Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can install multiple Office/Outlook versions on your computer.

So, the best is to **just try it** as it should work if you don't use the previous license anymore.

Comment: Agreed. You should be able to do a custom install and choose which items to install. Basically, deselect everything but Outlook.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!Thank you all for your great information.  I was concerned with this beinging a new computer I wanted to install this onto, I wanted to make sure I was not doing something that would harm it.  Thanks again!!